# InAppSettingKit custom bundle is not recognized on device

Tags: ios5, settings.bundle, inappsettingskit

I set up InAppSettingsKit and wish to have only certain volatile settings available from within the app. These would not be the same as what is found in settings.app from springboard. I added a bundle, InAppSettings.Bundle and created the appropriate plist files. It works as expected in the simulator but acts as though my new bundle does not exist on the device. The device shows only the same as the settings.app properties in settings.bundle/ root.plist.

How do I get the new bundle into users' devices without deleting and reinstalling the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it was a "case" of developer error. Apparently the case of the characters in the name of a file are not specific in the simulator. The files in my bundle were not correctly named. I had root.inApp.plist when it should have been Root.inApp.plist. Worked in simulator,not on the device.
Once I realized this and renamed the file, the device read and displayed the correct file as intended.
That was a waste of about 5 hours chasing my tale. I Hope this info helps someone avoid this same annoying oversight.